# FragmentTransaction add fragment after replace old fragment but onDestroyView called

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager, fragmenttransaction

I replaced FragmentA :

```
 FragmentManager fm = MainActivity.getGlobal().getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
 ft.addToBackStack(fragmentA.getClass().getSimpleName());
 ft.replace(relId, fragmentA,fragmentA.getClass().getSimpleName());
 ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

and add FragmentB :

```
FragmentManager fm = MainActivity.getGlobal().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(relId, fragmentB);
ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

After adding `FragmentA:onDestroyView` called, How fix it? I want FragmentB to add and Fragment Not DestroyView

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `replace()` is analogous to calling `remove()` on A and them calling `add()` on B hence it is not possible to save A when you replace it it's `onDestroy()`, on`DestroyView()` etc will be called.

But instead of calling `replace()` you can call `add()` for B add B on top of A without removing A and add B to back stack to navigate to A on back press

**Have a good day , Ali**

Comment: use `add` instead of `replace` it will add the fragment B on top of A rather replacing the A with B