# How to handle fragment backstack

Tags: android

I'm having problem with fragment. Lets try to understand my issue, I have two fragment `A` and `B`. When app start with main activity,i start fragment `A` as you can see :

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new MusicFragment())
                .commit();
```

When i click on a button, it starts fragment `B`

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new BarFragment())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

`Main problem` is after starting fragment `B`,when i pressed back to go back to fragment `A` , Fragment `A` Recreated with new state.
I don' want to recreate fragment `A`. I only want to start fragment from old state where i left. How to fix it ?

Comment: i answered -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62498487/fragmenttransaction-add-fragment-after-replace-old-fragment-but-ondestroyview-ca/62498976#62498976

Comment: show a example code. Answer this question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the `replace` method you should be calling the `add` method with a subsequent call to `addToBackStack` with an argument of `null`. The `add` method adds the fragement to the stack with a null tag and calling the `addToBackStack` with an argument of `null` then the current fragment is stopped upon commit. If the method is not called then the current fragment is destroyed and recreated when coming back.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container,new BarFragment())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

You can clearly find it in the documentation quote saying this:

> If you don't call addToBackStack() when you perform a transaction that
> removes a fragment, then that fragment is destroyed when the
> transaction is committed and the user cannot navigate back to it.
> Whereas, if you do call addToBackStack() when removing a fragment,
> then the fragment is stopped and is later resumed if the user
> navigates back.

Comment: what means ID in addToBackStack()

Comment: it can be `null` no problem

Comment: try removing the line `addToBackStack` from both fragments

Comment: Congrats bro , you got it. Problem is solved. Now it is working too good. Thanxxxx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216636/discussion-between-mukul-jangir-and-abhinav-chauhan).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points that need to be taken care while creating fragments.

Check the backstack if the fragment is already created.

If it was created previously pop it from the backstack and put it on top so that it is visible to the user.

If fragment is not present in backstack crate it and store it in backstack.

Create a method like below which will handle such situation.

```
private void openFragment(Fragment fragment_to_be_opened){
      String fragment_to_be_opened_name = fragment_to_be_opened.getClass().getName();
      FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
// fetching the fragment if it is present in backstack
      boolean fragment_allready_present = manager.popBackStackImmediate (fragment_to_be_opened_name, 0);
      if (!fragment_allready_present){ //fragment is not present in backstack so create it and save the name in //backstack
        FragmentTransaction fragment_trasition = manager.beginTransaction();
        fragment_trasition.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment_to_be_opened);
        fragment_trasition.addToBackStack(fragment_to_be_opened_name);
        fragment_trasition.commit();
      }
    }
```

Now call this method from the activity to open a new fragment like

// create instance of fragment and pass it to the open fragment method

```
Fragment myFragment = new myFragment();
 openFragment(myFragment);
```